# Error al ejecutar SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Estoy haciendo un `ActionResult` que me sirve tanto para hacer un `update` como para hacer un `insert`, dependiendo de la bandera que le pase como parámetro, esto ya lo había hecho con otros controladores y me funciona perfecto, pero con este me manda un error al ejecutar el método `SaveChanges()`, ya revise mi modelo y si se han actualizado las tablas de mi BD pero todo esta bien. genere un controlador con el `scaffolding` y me edita perfectamente pero con el mio no.

Mi `ActionResult`, el `SaveChanges` despues del else es el que hace el update y me marca el error

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CrEd([Bind(Include = "IdUsuario,Nombre,Contrasena,Descripcion,Estatus,IdRol")] Usuarios usuarios, int bandera)
    {
        if(bandera == 1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Usuarios.Add(usuarios);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.IdRol = new SelectList(db.UsuariosRol, "IdRol", "Nombre", usuarios.IdRol);
            return View(usuarios);
        }else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(usuarios).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.IdRol = new SelectList(db.UsuariosRol, "IdRol", "Nombre", usuarios.IdRol);
            return View(usuarios);
        }
    }
```

mi vista

```
 @model BackBolsaDeTrabajo.Data.Usuarios

  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "CrEd";
     string bandera = Request.QueryString["bandera"];

 }

 <h2>CrEd</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Usuarios</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="hidden" value="@Model.IdUsuario" name="IdUsuario" />
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" value="@bandera" name="bandera" />

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contrasena, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contrasena, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contrasena, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estatus)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdRol, "IdRol", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("IdRol", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdRol, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

El error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debería incluir el código de su vista, ¿Está enviando el `IdUsuario` a su controlador correctamente? . sería bueno que verifique esto.

Comment: Justo hace unos segundos, me percate que no estaba volviendo a pasar el IDUsuario, editare la pregunta y si quieres responde para que la ponga como respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error es común cuando no se le pasa un `clave` correcta, es decir clave `0` *por defecto* al `contexto` ya sea para guardar, actualizar o eliminar datos.
Para corregir debe asegurarse que en su vista tenga el campo `hidden` con el `id` correctamente de la siguiente forma.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdUsuario)
```